# Aggregating multiple columns of a pandas dataframe using custom functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

EDIT: Because several people have already gone this route, I don't want to get rid of arbFun - I used a mean here because it was a simple example, but it's a stand in for a much more complicated function that cannot be easily removed. It is important that the arbFun take the inputs of two separate columns and output a single value per group. Within that restriction, we can modify arbFun as we please, but any solution that gets rid of it entirely is probably not workable.

Bear with my stupidly complicated simple example here - I really tried to get an easy version of my very complicated problem.

Say I have a dataframe `data` and a function `arbfun` given by the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Label1':[1,2,2,1,1,2],
                     'Label2':['north', 'north', 'north', 'south', 'south', 'south'],
                     'A':[2,4,6,8,10,12],'B':[4,1,37,1,1,1]})

def arbFun(col1, col2):

    """
  Calculates the average value of col1 for all values of (col2 == 1).

  Args:
    col1: A pandas Series containing the values to be averaged.
    col2: A pandas Series containing the filter conditions.

  Returns:
    The average value of col1 for all values of (col2 == 1).
  """

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':col1, 'Col2':col2})

    # Filter the data based on the condition
    filtered_data = df[df['Col2'] == 1]

    # Calculate the average
    if len(filtered_data) > 0:
        average = filtered_data['Col1'].mean()
    else:
        average = None  # Return None if no data meets the condition

    return average
```

If I run ArbFun on the whole of data, I get a value of 8.5. So far so good. But now, I want to group by my two label columns and output the results of my ArbFun, as well as some additional information.

```
output = data.groupby(['Label1', 'Label2']).agg(
    Column_A =('A', 'sum'),
    Filtered_Mean = lambda x: arbFun(x['A'], x['B'])
)
```

Now this should output something like

```
Label1,Label2,Column_A,Filtered_Mean
1,'north',2,None
2,'north',10,4
1,'south',18,9
2,'south',12,12
```

But instead, I get a type error: `TypeError: Must provide 'func' or tuples of '(column, aggfunc)`. I have tried hard to understand where this is coming from but so far have failed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use `DataFrame.groupby().apply()` and return a `pd.Series`:

```py
def group_fn(g):
    return pd.Series(
        {"Column_A": g["A"].sum(), "Filtered_Mean": g.loc[g["B"] == 1, "A"].mean()}
    )


data = data.groupby(["Label1", "Label2"], as_index=False).apply(group_fn)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
   Label1 Label2  Column_A  Filtered_Mean
0       1  north       2.0            NaN
1       1  south      18.0            9.0
2       2  north      10.0            4.0
3       2  south      12.0           12.0
```

---

EDIT: If you have to use `arbFun` function you can do:

```py
def group_fn(g):
    return pd.Series(
        {"Column_A": g["A"].sum(), "Filtered_Mean": arbFun(g["A"], g["B"])}
    )


data = data.groupby(["Label1", "Label2"], as_index=False).apply(group_fn)
print(data)
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the other answer: I don't want to simplify ArbFun and get rid of the function, because it's a stand-in for something much more complicated and not-reducable. So any solution that gets rid of ArbFun is a no-go here. How could I impliment this kind of pd.Series output within the context of ArbFun? We can modify that function plenty, but there needs to be a lambda function call in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

It seems inefficient to create and apply custom function.

1. Filter, then calculate the mean, and merge the result to sum table.

```
g1 = data.groupby(['Label1', 'Label2'])['A']
g2 = data[data['B'].eq(1)].groupby(['Label1', 'Label2'])['A']
out = (g1.sum().to_frame(name='Column_A').sort_index(level=1)
         .assign(Filtered_Mean=g2.mean()).reset_index())
```

out

```
   Label1 Label2  Column_A  Filtered_Mean
0       1  north         2            NaN
1       2  north        10            4.0
2       1  south        18            9.0
3       2  south        12           12.0
```

---

2. I think Method 1 is better, but if the simplicity and intuitiveness of the code are important, you can also use the code below.

```
g = data.groupby(['Label1', 'Label2'])['A']
cond = data['B'].eq(1)
out1 = g.agg(Column_A=sum, Filtered_Mean=lambda x: x.where(cond).mean())
```

out1:

```
               Column_A  Filtered_Mean
Label1 Label2                         
1      north          2            NaN
       south         18            9.0
2      north         10            4.0
       south         12           12.0
```

Performing `sort_index` and `reset_index` on `out1` results in the same output as `out`.

Comment: So, the actual function has nothing to do with averaging. It's much more complicated, but I wanted to use a simplified version so people could get what I'm going for here. Suffice it to say that the use of a user-generated function is non-optional, and that the function references two columns to generate a single output for each group.

Comment: @Jared Brewer Your approach is not in the right direction because `agg` cannot access data from multiple columns simultaneously. so, cant modify your code. Additionally, even if you think your complex mechanism requires a custom function, it is likely that it does not.

Comment: Ok. The actual version of this code is a function that takes as input two column variables (a vertical slice of atmospheric chemical measurements and a second of corresponding pressure levels) and then interpolates the pressure levels to find what pressure corresponds to the vertical level of the 90th percentile of the aggregated column - that is, at what pressure is 90% of the column chemical beneath you. I can do this in R with Nest -> mutate -> map; what's the right way to do it in python? Apply?